# Previous versions of Linux in Grub?

Tags: kernel, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

So I have linux versions 3.0.whatever-12 to 15 on my laptop, and they made a ton of icons in burg before I broke that. So how can I get rid of them? They appear in "previous versions" in grub.